# how to put action like back button in the APP LOGO using API LV8 in android?

Tags: android, android-menu

what are the ways in puting back button in APP Logo using only api lv8?
what are the alternative without using api lv8+ like without using actionbar..

Answer (score 0):

You can use ActionBarCompat from appcompat support library.

- http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html

Comment: my prof said we cant use any suport library thats our chalenge, is it posible to use only api lv8 only in creating the back buton logo without using suport libraries?